# Bound of a complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question from an old prelim in complex analysis. Show that if $f$ is an analytic function such that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{1-|z|}$ for $|z|<1$, then $|f'(0)| \leq 4$. I tried using both Cauchy's $ML$-Estimates along with the Cauchy Integral Formula and even the Schwarz-Pick Lemma, but I still do not get the desired result. Any suggestions as to how best to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: By Cauchy's Integral Formula, we have $f'(0) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\oint_{|z| = R}\dfrac{f(z)}{z^2}\,dz$ for any $R \in (0,1)$

Now, try bounding that integral in terms of $R$. Then, pick the best value of $R \in (0,1)$.

> The best value of $R$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Aha! Of course, $|z|=R<1$. D'oh!